# NextJS resolvedUrl is string '/null'

Tags: next.js

We have:

```
pages/[providerSlug]/index.ts
pages/account/index.ts
```

When we visit `/account` (with no query), this code in `[providerSlug]/index.ts` gets hit:

```
export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {
   console.dir(context)
}

outputs:
  ...
  query: { providerSlug: 'null' },
  resolvedUrl: '/null',
  params: { providerSlug: 'null' },
```

Two questions:

1. Why is `[providerSlug]/index.ts` being hit? Shouldn't only `account/index.ts` be hit? I tried adding `getServerSideProps` to `account/index.ts` as well (it doesn't have it), made no difference.
2. Where is resolvedUrl & query.providerSlug getting set? I cannot find how this is getting set but it must be in our code somewhere -- what gets hit before `getServerSideProps` that I should look at?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
pages/[providerSlug]/index.ts
pages/account/index.ts
```

Set up

```
pages/[providerSlug].ts
pages/account.ts
```

`/account` should now correctly take precedence on `/foo`

If you ever need to capture `/foo/bar` you can setup

```
pages/[providerSlug]/[secondarySlug].ts
```

or if it's a full slug, you can put an optional catch all route : https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#catch-all-routes